# bash calculations with numbers from files

Tags: bash

I am trying to do a simple thing:

To get the second number in the the line with the second occurence of the word TER and lower it by one and further process it. `The tr -s ' '` is there because the file is not delimited by tabs, but by different amounts of whitespaces.

My script:

```
first_res_atombumb= grep 'TER' tata_sbox_cuda.pdb | head -n 2 | tail -1 |tr -s ' '| cut -f 2 -d ' '

echo $((first_res_atombumb-1))
```

but this only returnes:

255

-1

Of course I want to have 254.

adding `| tr -d '\n'` does not help either, what on earth is going on? I have already asked several people at work noone seems to know.

the lines in question look linke this

```
TER     128      DA3     4 

TER     255      DA3     8
```

and if I apply  `grep 'TER' tata_sbox_cuda.pdb | head -n 2 | tail -1  | tr -s ' '| cut     -f 2 -d ' '` in the command line i get what i expect, just `255`

Comment: Can you paste the data line?

Comment: There isn't enough information here for me to replicate the problem you're having or verify a solution I might come up with. Please include your original data, along with your expected results. If you can replicate the problem using your own sample data, that would help quite a bit.

Comment: sorry just forgot it

Comment: the file is really large so I just gave the lines i want to use further

Comment: not sure what you mean by "replicate the problem using your own sample data" but if i use a file containing TER 666 more stuff I get the same result 666-1 not 665

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash, I'd write

```
n_ter=0
while read -a words; do 
    if [[ ${words[0]} == TER ]] && (( ++n_ter == 2 )); then 
        echo $(( ${words[1]} - 1 ))
    fi
done < file
```

but I'd use awk

```
awk '$1 == "TER" && ++n == 2 {print $2 - 1}' file
```

---

The problem with your code: you forgot to use the `$()` [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) syntax

```
first_res_atombumb= grep 'TER' tata_sbox_cuda.pdb | head -n 2 | tail -1 |tr -s ' '| cut -f 2 -d ' '
# .................^...............................................................................^
echo $((first_res_atombumb-1))
```

You're setting the variable to an empty string in the environment of the grep command. Then, since you're not capturing the output of that pipeline, "255" is printed to the terminal. Because the variable is unset in your current shell, you get `echo $((-1))`

All you need is:

```
first_res_atombumb=$(grep 'TER' tata_sbox_cuda.pdb | head -n 2 | tail -1 |tr -s ' '| cut -f 2 -d ' ')
# .................^^...............................................................................^
```

But I'd still use awk.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you can solve it using `AWK`:

`awk 'BEGIN{v=0} $1 == "TER" {v++;if (v==2) {print $2-1 ;exit}}' tata_sbox_cuda.pdb`

### Explanation:

1. `BEGIN{v=0}` declaring and nulling the variable.
2. `$1 == "TER"` execute the command in {} only if it's the second occurence of TER.
3. `{v++;if (v==2) {print $2-1 ;exit}}'` increase the value of v and check if it's 2, in this case subtract 1 from the second field and display, exit afterwards (will make the processing faster and will skip unnecessary lines).

Comment: pedantically, it's not required to initialize the value to zero. awk treats unset variables as zero in numeric context.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about that.